# Samsung Galaxy SIII not Recognized

Tags: samsung, samsung-kies

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII which I'm attempting to pull photos off of - but I am having trouble doing so. I've attempted to use Kies to pull the photos off - but it just says loading... loading... loading... forever. The computer seems to recognize the phone (it is shown under device manager) but it never seems to appear under My Computer (this may be related to why Kies does not recognize it either.)

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you enabled USB Storage after you plug in your phone?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tgllLpc6zI

Comment: That's where things get a bit tricky... the phone has a bad LCD (the digitzer is good - so I can do a little bit of input by setting a working galaxy s3 next to it and following along - but I'm literally shooting in the dark so I was hoping for a software or command line based solution of some sort)

Comment: ...plus a bunch more over at [android.se].

Answer (score 1):

When I plug my S3 into my Windows 7/8 computers (after installing Kies to get the drivers), it just shows up as a "portable media player" under My Computer and is easily accessible.

If yours isn't, *and you've tried more than one computer*, then I suspect more than just the screen on the S3 is broken.

Comment: Would it still be recognized by the device manager in that case? I'm pretty sure it's still alive in some sense since it still has audible notifications coming from the device and it is recognized by device manager.

Comment: Just because it can see it in the device manager, doesn't mean the drivers can communicate with it.  I suggest trying it another Windows 7+ computer, and if it doesn't basically "just work" (after installing Kies) then consider it busted.  I've gone through two S3's attached to multiple Windows 7/8 machines, and never had any difficulty getting it to be recognized.  If it DOES work on the other computer, then you probably need to manually clean out the existing drivers and registry references and reinstall the drivers on the problematic computer.

Comment: I just used Droid@Screen to view the device - it's working perfectly. I'm going to use a cloud backup service to upload the pictures and call it a day.